How to deal with dynamic elements with Selenium on pagespeed
I am using slelenium with python. I am trying to create an automation on this site https://pagespeed.web.dev/
I'm running into trouble with the "analyze" button as everytime it is clicked it's element name changes and I need to click it multiple times. For example I will use it's CSS selector of #yDmH0d > c-wiz > div.T4LgNb > div > div.ZVTDqc > form > div.VfPpkd-dgl2Hf-ppHlrf-sM5MNb > button > div.VfPpkd-RLmnJb and after the button is clicked the 3rd "div" changes e.g. div.ZVTDqc  will change to div.8saAE
Is there a way to account for this?

You can simply use the XPath
//span[text()='Analyze']

